# How to prevent over-eager Jedi autocompletion in Vim

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, jedi-vim

I use Vim and [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) to code Python and the autocompletion fails to detect some member objects with the [`recordclass`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordclass) and `argparse` packages and makes over-eager suggestions.

Consider this case:

```
from recordclass import recodclass

class Foo(recordclass('Foo', ['bar', 'bar2', 'bar3'])):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'custom string'

x = Foo()
```

Now, typing `x.` automatically inserts `x.__str__`, even if `bar`, `bar2`, and `bar3` are possible options.

A similar thing happens here:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
ap = ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-x', '--some-var', type=str)
args = ap.parse_args()
```

Now, typing `args.` inserts `args._`, even if `args.some_var` is a valid member.

Can I get Jedi to recognize all members or at least make it not insert the "unambiguous" characters (`__str__` and `_`) automaticaly?

Comment: I use the addon deoplete instead due to issues like this. It's autocomplete stays out of the way most of time.

Comment: Have you tried to use `:set completeopt -= "longest"`?

Comment: @ApolloFortyNine: thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @DaveHalter: thank you, that is a good workaround (it makes it a bit slower when the autocomplete function works correctly, though)